# Android - HTTP Get request on LAN

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to get a page's source which is a plain text (no html tags) from a webserver on LAN. But I am always getting empty string in return and If I open the same URI in browser I can see the text. Following is my code:

```
                String url = "http://192.168.1.40/touchscreens/get.qsp?display=1";

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

                request.setURI(new URI(url));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }

                String page = sb.toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), page, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and one more thing when I enter the same URL in android emulator browser I don't see anything. Am i missing something?

Comment: shouldn't there be some port while calling using IP?

Comment: The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to StringBuffer, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

Comment: @thinksteep: It's working on Port 80 and as I said I am successfully able to see the text when I paste the same url in google chrome.

Comment: What status code do you have in your response? Check with response.getStatus().

Comment: But in above code you missed port entry. As well as findout status code.

Comment: @Jan-Henk Status code I received is 200. And when I paste the same URL in android emulator browser I don't see anything, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you should debug your HTTP requests using fiddler (see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This should debug the internet requests from your browser and your app and show you if your requests are missing the necessary headers.

Comment: this is my request's raw view from fiddler2:

GET http://192.168.1.40/touchscreens/get.qsp?display=1&b=1326747904130 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.40
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Comment: The questions you should be asking are: what does fiddler say about your Android app vs what your browser says. You said the browser works, fiddler should tell you what is different.